# Calculating (add) HEX values

Tags: vb.net, hex, calculator

i am trying to do the following:Looking up values in a .txt file, such as "DD" which will be written into a string variable, and then converted into a Byte variable. I then want to add to this, for example BB + 10 = CB

For testing, my code is the following

```
Public reqw As String = "BB" 'normally comes from the txt. file
Public btansw as byte
Public finansw as string 

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim MyByte As Byte
    If Byte.TryParse(reqw, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier, Nothing, MyByte) Then
        btansw = MyByte 
    Else
        RichTextBox3.Text &= "Err2"

    End If
```

This code converts the string "BB" into bytes.
The acutal problem is the following:

```
finansw = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversion.Hex(btansw+ 10) 

    RichTextBox3.Text &= finansw
```

This gives me "C5" as result in the RichTextBox but it is supposed to be "CB".

Can someone explain what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I didn't include this in my answer so I'll put it here to hopefully ensure that the OP sees it. Note that a number is just a number, no matter how you represent it. The fact that `btansw` is the result of parsing a hex string doesn't mean that it is hex itself and there's no requirement to use a hex literal when doing arithmetic with it. If you wanted to add 0x10, i.e. sixteen, then you could have just used `16`. It works exactly the same as `&H10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding 10, i.e. ten, so the result is correct. If what you actually want to add is 0x10, i.e. sixteen, then you need to actually use a hex value. In VB, you use the `&H` prefix to indicate a hex literal.

```vb
finansw = (btansw + &H10).ToString("X2")
```

Let's not write our VB.NET like we were still using VB6.